# Java taking too long to render tiles from a PNG image

Tags: java, render, tiles

I'm trying to render a level (1600 / 448) in a (600 / 448) screen from a PNG file. It tries to render but it doesn't succeed, I think that it stops the game loop while doing so. And I think this is happening because there are many tiles but I don't really know how I can go around it.

```
 public void loadLevel(BufferedImage image) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    for (int xx = 0; xx < width; xx++) { //width = 1600
        for (int yy = 0; yy < height; yy++) { //height = 448;
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(xx,yy));
            int red = c.getRed();
            int green = c.getGreen();
            int blue = c.getBlue();

            if (red == 225 && blue == 225 & green == 225) {
                objectHandler.add(new GrassRight(xx * 32, yy * 32, ObjectId.GrassRight));
            } else if (red == 129 && blue == 250 & green == 212) {
                objectHandler.add(new Player(xx * 32, yy * 32, objectHandler, ObjectId.Player));
           } else if (red == 0 && blue == 0 && green == 0) {
               objectHandler.add(new Dirt(xx * 32, yy * 32, ObjectId.Dirt));

            } else if (red == 144 && blue == 144 & green == 213) {
                objectHandler.add(new Grass(xx * 32, yy * 32, ObjectId.Grass));

            } else if (red == 38 && blue == 56 & green == 50) {
                objectHandler.add(new GrassLeft(xx * 32, yy * 32, ObjectId.GrassLeft));

            } else if (red == 62 && blue == 35 & green == 39) {
                objectHandler.add(new SlideRight(xx * 32, yy * 32, ObjectId.SlideRight));

            } else if (red == 191 && blue == 12 & green == 54) {
                objectHandler.add(new SlideLeft(xx * 32, yy * 32, ObjectId.SlideLeft));

            } else if (red == 127 && blue == 194 & green == 87) {
                objectHandler.add(new DownSlideLeft(xx * 32, yy * 32, ObjectId.DownSlideLeft));

            } else if (red == 49 && blue == 146 & green == 27) {
                objectHandler.add(new DownSlideRight(xx * 32, yy * 32, ObjectId.DownSlideRight));
            }
        }
    }
}


public void init() {
    System.out.println("Loading...");
    LoadingHandler loadingHandler = new LoadingHandler();
    level = loadingHandler.loadImage("/Level1.png");
    objectHandler = new ObjectHandler();
    cameraHandler = new CameraHandler(0, 0);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler(objectHandler));
    loadLevel(level);
    System.out.println("Done!");
}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g2d.translate(cameraHandler.getX(), cameraHandler.getY());
    System.out.println("Rendering!");
    objectHandler.render(g);
    System.out.println("Rendered!");
    g2d.translate(-cameraHandler.getX(), -cameraHandler.getY());
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();

}

public class ObjectHandler {
public LinkedList<ObjectManager> object = new LinkedList<>();

ObjectManager tempObject;

public void tick() {
    for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
        tempObject = object.get(i);
        tempObject.tick(object);
    }
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
        tempObject = object.get(i);
        tempObject.render(g);
    }
}

public void add(ObjectManager object) {
    this.object.add(object);

}
```

And it gives out this output:

```
Loading...
Done!
Rendering!
```

PNG:

[image]

Comment: Did the process run completely or it halted halfway?

Comment: @user3437460 It halted halfway in fact it didnt print out "Rendered"

Comment: Code isn't complete ... we can guess wide range of problems.

Comment: There are quite a bit of missing parts in your given code. I don't know what your current class is and how is objectHandler defined.

Comment: @JacekCz yeah I think it has to do with the amount of tiles because if you leave it for some minutes it does say "rendered" but I still get a white screen

Comment: @user3437460 I updated the code with the ObjectHandler class

Comment: Why do you need to create an object for each pixel of the image?

Comment: @MauricePerry to render in its right axes

Comment: what's in the png?

Comment: @MauricePerry Different colors to identify the tiles

Comment: Can you post the png?

Comment: @MauricePerry https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYjOl.png

Comment: 1) Rendering image one pixel at time is not going to work well; 2) We need ObjectManager.render code; 3) why xx * 32, yy * 32 ? If you want tiles to take 32x32 pixels, then why do you iterate through original image 1 by 1 pixel? In any case, you will end up with some huge numbers which will probably end off-screen?

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski 1) I dont know how I can do it differently 2) ObjectManager,render is an abstract code 3) I will arrange that Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating an object for each pixel (that is 716'800 objects), create one object per rectangular region (15 objects).

UPDATE:

In the class ObjectManager, add two int fields: width and height, then render the whole rectangle instead of just a single pixel (or 32x32 square). You can still use the PNG to initialize the objects, but with a smarter algorithm that would not recreate a new object for each pixel.

Comment: Could you please give me a lead were to start Because I have no idea how I'm going to do that

Comment: How are these objects (GrassRight, Player, SlideLeft, etc...) rendered?

Comment: In the GrassRight class I have a render method: public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawRect((int) x, (int) y, 32, 32);
    }
and then its read in the ObjectHandler class from a for loop:public void render(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
            tempObject = object.get(i);
            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    } then this is called in the render method in the game class

Comment: It's a very bad idea to declare tempObject as a field, BTW. Declare it in the block where it is used: ObjectManager tempObject = object.get(i);

Comment: Okay thanks what do you suggest doing instead of tempObject

Comment: I think I managed to render but Its laggy now. What I did was changed the color of dirt to another color because transparent was black too and I did the rendering in an ecnahnted loop instead for (ObjectManager temp : object) {
            temp.render(g);
        }

Comment: I made the lag go away but now if I move the canvas to the edge of the monitor the canvas turns white